# Google Drive Api check if user is signed in

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I work with Google Drive Api and now I have simple app (similar to https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) but I want to add login page with two options (login with google drive and login as guest) showing only if user is not sign in with any account. How can I check it? I want to show this activity only when after click on 'login with google drive' I'll see dialog with list of accounts to choose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'guest' login on Google Drive. Only the accounts 'registered' on your Android Device (see Settings > Accounts) can access the Drive (their GooDrives).

There are 2 ways to handle the account creation / picking.

1/ You DO NOT specify valid (registered on your device) account's email

```
GoogleApiClient GAC = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
  //.setAccountName(email)
  .addApi(Drive.API)
  .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
  .addConnectionCallbacks(...)
  .addOnConnectionFailedListener(...)
  .build();
```

and GooPlaySvcs will pop-up the account picker dialog allowing your user to select a valid account or create a new one. Your app will not know what account the user selected / created.

2/ You DO specify valid (registered on your device) account's email

```
GoogleApiClient GAC = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
  .setAccountName(email)
  .addApi(Drive.API)
  .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
  .addConnectionCallbacks(...)
  .addOnConnectionFailedListener(...)
  .build();
```

Now, how do you get the `email`? You can't specify just an arbitrary email. Again, you have to use one of the device's registered ones via `account picker`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
...
static final int REQ_ACCPICK = 999;
...
startActivityForResult(AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
  new String[]{GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE}, true, null, null, null, null), REQ_ACCPICK);
...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int rslt, Intent data) {
  if (
    request == REQ_ACCPICK &&
    rslt == RESULT_OK && 
    data != null && data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME) != null
  )
     email = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
     ...
```

Please see the typical handling of this by following the `REQ_ACCPICK` in this [code](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/gdaademo/MainActivity.java). You have to add an account manager (like UT.AM class in the mentioned demo) and persist the current account's email.

Good Luck

Comment: I know that there is no 'guest' login on Google Drive. I want to have two options: login with google drive or work as guest (without google drive functionality) so I have to display this options only when user is logged out from google (I wont see account picker after click on first option). I only need this knowledge whether user is logged in or not.

Comment: App's private account manager with persistence (option #2) under [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro). Or, (under the [REST Api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk)), you can use GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(...).setSelectedAccountName(email) / getSelectedAccount(). Both need the 'GET_ACCOUNTS' permission.